# Drag and drop sketch application for Windows?

Tags: windows, drawing

I am looking for a Windows application that

- Allows you to make basic drawings (doesn't have to necessarily do much else, but is ok if it does)
- **most important:** When you've made a drawing, allows you to drag that drawing and drop it into Microsoft Word and Evernote, or turn it into a jpg/png/etc file by dragging it into a folder. The important thing is that it should take only one step to do so, rather than having to first save or export it, or something like that.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just copy it over the clipboard? That wouldn't create any intermediate files

Comment: @Mawg, is there a general way to do that? I'm not aure how to do that except if the application happens to have a special function for it

Comment: From the Windows menu, look for "snipping tool". Let me know if that works; if not, I will try to think of something else

Comment: @Mawg, I've tried snipping tool a while, but it's not entirely satisfactory: * you have to open both the snipping tool and the drawing app, and you have to have them open at the same time. * whenever you want to snip a drawing, you have to first click on the snipping tool, and possibly drag it in the right place, and then on the snipping button, then you have to select what you want to copy, and only then can you paste it (rather than being able to just drag and drop the image in one action). * also, whenever you've copied something, the snipping tool opens at the copied place, so that...

Comment: so that you have to remove the snipping tool from that place again when you want to draw again. All these actions make it so that it's rather cumbersome to work this way. I want to use this to very quickly make sketches and add them to a document, and the fact that its a bit cumbersome just makes it so that its very not-fluid to add the sketches.

Comment: It would help if you can give an exact list of where you want to drop, or even just say that you know them & they all accept drop.

Comment: @Mawg , I actually already listed them both, but sorry, I should have been more clear. I care primarily about evernote, and secondarily about microsoft word.  They both support drop.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Now all we need is a drawing app that supports dag :-) Is it ok if you have to Ctrl-A first?

Comment: @Mawg , sorry for the delay, I see now I didn’t respond to your comment. Yes, cntrl-A is ok I think

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you are going to find an app. If you can code, it is easy enough with [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). If not, consider using a macro recorder, to record and later play back keystrokes with a single hotkey